# to appeal to the senses

Tags: phrase-meaning, vocabulary

I am trying to precisely grasp the meaning of the phrase "appeal to the senses", and would like to test my understanding by paraphrasing two sentences inspired by ones I have read on the Web.

Merriam Webster's says about *appeal* in sense 2b:

> an attempt to make someone do or accept something as right or proper
>   by saying things that are directed at a person's feelings, attitudes,
>   etc. - + to
>
> *▪ The author makes an appeal to the reader's emotions. ▪ an appeal to reason ▪ an appeal to the intellect*

Would you consider these two sentences:

- These techniques use language directed at the senses.
- The writer using sensory language is trying to stimulate the reader's <strike>sensual</strike> memory to catch their interest

semantically synonymous or very similar to these:

- These techniques appeal to the senses.
- The writer is trying to appeal to the reader's senses.

Comment: BTW-comment,  What do you mean "**sensual memory**", do you refer to sexual pleasures and these sorts of things ?

Comment: My bad, that was a slip! I meant sensory memory

Comment: I think there's something of a "cognitive disjunct" in *The writer is trying to appeal to the reader's senses.* The only context where I can really make sense of it is if the writer uses very evocative/visceral references (to mouth-watering tastes, attractive aromas, etc.) that make the reader ***imagine*** he's having those sensory experiences while engaged in the essentially ***cerebral*** process of reading. But even there it would be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I guess it could make sense if you used *sense* rather than *senses* (e.g., we all have some sense of justice, sense of humor, and so on).

Comment: @DamkerngT. In the context it is used *appeal to the senses* refers to the five physical senses

Comment: Oh, sorry! I read your question only halfway and thought you were trying to paraphrase some examples in the dictionary. Personally, I don't think "appealing to the senses" and "directed at the senses" are the same (and I don't expect to find them, especially the latter, except in certain sorts of writing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Senses" here means taste, hearing, sight, and/or touch. "Appeal" here basically means "give pleasure to", though it crosses over into "requests". So "this appeals to the senses" means it gives pleasure to a person's taste, hearing, etc. If, for example, a movie had great music and beautiful scenery, you might say, "This movie appealed to the senses." It might or might not have an interesting story -- that would be beside the point. When I said the meaning of "appeal" borders on "request", I meant that the meaning of "this appeals to the senses" also carries a connotation of "it asks the audience to appreciate it on a sensual level".

"Appeals to the senses" is something of the oppose of "appeals to the intellect" or "appeals to reason". A work of art might appeal to both the senses and to intellect, but they're different things. Beautiful music and scenary appeal to the senses; a logical argument or a finely crafted story appeal to the intellect.

Answer (score 2):

"Appeal to the senses" is a collocation that means the writer's choices seek to have the reader *recall* or *imagine* sensation.

> When the wasp stung my wrist, there was a searing pain along my entire
>   forearm, which felt as though it had been splashed with hot cooking oil.

The 'appeal' can be to pleasurable or to painful experience, so it is not necessarily something we would consider an *appealing* sensation.

One can write in a way that does not try to invoke sense memory, even though it refers to what is normally a process involving one or more of the senses.

> They masticated and ingested the protein set before them.

Comment: A great answer. "recall or imagine sensation." "try to invoke sense memory." Thank you TRomano.

Is there a typo in this sentence "The 'appeal' **can be to** pleasurable or **to** painful experience" or is it a valid grammatical structure that means due to?

Comment: Since **or** structures can imply that the elements on either side of **or** are synonyms or analogues rather than mutually exclusive choices, I prefer to repeat the preposition; though it is not ungrammatical not to repeat it.  "Oratory can appeal **to** base instincts or **to** our better angels" versus "Oratory can appeal **to** base instincts or our better angels".  It is an appeal to pleasurable or to painful experience.

Comment: So, in other words, **or** can come between prepositional phrases, or between the objects of the (single) preposition.

Comment: Actually I did not have a problem with or. I had it with "can be to sth" but I emphasized the second to because both came together. Now I realized how imprecise I was. Sorry about that. But on the bright side, you have answered my question in the process already. Thanks